# loop for Cursor1.moveToPosition() in android

Tags: android

I want to get data in the first column of all row from my database and convert to String[]
...

```
List<String> item1 = new ArrayList<String>();
// c is a cursor which pointed from a database
for(int i=0;i<=nombre_row;i++)
    {
        c.moveToPosition(i);
        item1.add(c.getString(0));
    }
String[] strarray = new String[item1.size()];
item1.toArray(strarray );
```

I've tried to comment step by step, and found that the problem is in the Loop for....
Please help... thanks in advance for all answer.

Comment: Hello Edward, welcome to SO. Please choose a valid answer if your question has been answered, thanks :)

Comment: dear m0skit0 : to be truth, I don't really know how to be here. I just search something related to my jobs, and found that SO is a good forum to discus about problem, and I try to ask my problem here... I found the best answers for me....... how to choose a valid answer ? Thanks :D

Comment: You already did! :) And SO is not a forum ;) You might want to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/about)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public String[] getData()
{
    Cursor cursor = this.db.query(/your query/);

    if(cursor.getCount() >0)
    {
        String[] str = new String[cursor.getCount()];
        int i = 0;

        while (cursor.moveToNext())
        {
             str[i] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Columname));
             i++;
         }
        return str;
    }
    else
    {
        return new String[] {};
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I got it work :

```
c.moveToFirst();
                do
                {
                    item1.add(c.getString(0).toString());
                    //i++;
                }while(c.moveToNext());
```

Comment: This will fail if `Cursor` instance has no results or is `null`.

Comment: Will also fail if it's empty. Look at Sardor's answer or at mine in your other question. Have fun!